# How to convert a ColorDistance from "CIE76" to "CIE2000"?

Tags: color

Consider, two unknown colors whose `ColorDistance`(Euclidean Distance (Default) in the CIE LAB color space) is `10` (say), where `L` ranges from 0 to 100, `a` from `-128` to `127` and `b` from `-128` to `127`. Is it possible to find the corresponding `ColorDistance` with the `DistanceFunction->"CIE2000"`?

**Edit 1:**

Basically, I need to calculate the JND (Just Noticeable Difference) value for the `DistanceFunction->"CIE2000"`. According to the CIE2000 documentation, the JND value is 1 (where `L` ranges from 0 to 100, `a` from `-128` to `127` and `b` from `-128` to `127`). However, since in *Mathematica* `L` ranges from `0` to `1` while `a` and `b` typically range from `-1` to `1`, I don't know how to find the corresponding JND value in `Mathematica`.

Comment: Knowing the distance between two points in one metric space doesn't tell you the distance in another metric space. I would be very surprised if two color spaces' metrics were isomorphic.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this? Do you not have access to the original colors for some reason? At any rate, the formulas for the color distance can be found by searching online. The formulas are pretty complicated.

Comment: @Searke Actually, I need the JND (just noticeable difference) threshold limit which is `5` (worst case) according to this (https://wisotop.de/assets/2017/DeltaE-%20Survey-2.pdf) [page 15, section 6.2] and I need the corresponding distance value for `DistanceFunction->"CIE2000"`

Answer (score 2):

As @Searke pointed out in the comments, it is in general not possible to compute the distance  according to one metric given the distance according to another one. A simple example that clearly demonstrates this is the following:

```
{a,b,c}=LABColor/@{{0,0,0},{1,0,0},{0,1,0}};

ColorDistance@@@{{a,b},{a,c}}
(* {1.,1.} *)

ColorDistance[##,DistanceFunction->"CIE2000"]&@@@{{a,b},{a,c}}
(* {1.,0.307876} *)
```

As you can see, both color pairs have distance 1 in the default metric but have completely different distances according to the CIE-2000 metric.